# How to open the "save as" pop up on browser, while using google cloud storage api to doawnoald a file

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm setting up a Flask web application where the user can download a software that I developed. 
The setup file of the software is on the Google cloud storage.

I'm actually able to download the file on my web app using the GCS API and by adding the path where I want to dowload the file.

```py
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    print('test start')
    storage_client = storage_connexion()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('downloading_file')
    blob = bucket.blob('TEST.txt')
    blob.download_to_filename('C:/Users/my.name/Desktop/test/TEST.txt')
    print('test done')
    return render_template('download.html')
```

What I want to do is => when I try to download the file from my web app, I'll get the "save as" pop up on the browser and choose the path manually.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file ? as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37937923/11516012

Comment: Yes it's working thanks a lot :)